# WSAEAFNOSUPPORT error

Tags: winsock2

Hi 
I am implementing P2P chatting application where server will mediator for exchangeing IP and port to connecting peer.
I am getting WSAEAFNOSUPPORT 10047 error .

I have created UDP
socket

sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP );
then iam binding it to local ip and port.

if (bind(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&localaddr,sizeof(localaddr))<0) 
    {
        Error_Code("create_socket:bind()");
        return -1;
    }

then I am contacting the server.

// connecting with server

sendto(sockfd,pBuffer,sizeof (nMessageType),0,(const sockaddr *)&config.serverAddr,size);

server keeps track of the other connected peer.once peer connects to the server it return ip and port of other peer.so a peer can use IP and port to directly connect to other peer.
but i am getting error while sending data to to other peer

// sending data to peer

int ret = sendto(sockfd,sendBuf,
sizeof(nMessagetype),0,(const sockaddr *)&m_peer.publicaddr,sockAddLen);
it return 10047 WSAEAFNOSUPPORT error.

Here I am using same socket to contact server and other peer is this reason for this?
I don't understand what is going wrong here.
It is able to connect with server properly but it is failing  to connect other peer.

Comment: Did you solve it? Did you get around to check that the two families are the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointed out in the [sendto](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740148%28VS.85%29.aspx) and for the actual error message [WSAEAFNOSUPPORT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740668%28VS.85%29.aspx#winsock.wsaeafnosupport_2) the address you are using to send to is not of the same family as the socket you are sending on.

You have to make sure that the address in `m_peer.publicaddr` is of the same family as `sockfd`.
For instance, if you send an address for IPv6, `AF_INET` will not work (it would have to be `AF_INET6`)